# Pegasos parameter tuning

Tags: machine-learning, svm, dlib

I'm trying to tune pegasos algorithm parameters without no luck.

Here is simple example using 6 one-dimensional points.

```
void dlib_svm_test()
{
    for(double lambda= 10e-10;lambda<=10e10;lambda*=10)
    {
        typedef dlib::matrix<double, 0, 1> sample_type;
        typedef dlib::linear_kernel<sample_type> kernel_type;

        dlib::svm_pegasos<kernel_type> pegasos;

        cout << lambda <<endl;

        pegasos.set_lambda(lambda);
        pegasos.set_kernel(kernel_type());

        std::vector<sample_type> samples(6);
        sample_type sample;
        sample.set_size(1);

        sample(0)= 188.0d;
        samples[0]= sample;
        sample(0)= 168.0d;
        samples[1]= sample;
        sample(0)= 191.0d;
        samples[2]= sample;
        sample(0)= 150.0d;
        samples[3]= sample;
        sample(0)= 154.0d;
        samples[4]= sample;
        sample(0)= 124.0d;
        samples[5]= sample;

        pegasos.train(samples[0],+1);
        pegasos.train(samples[1],+1);
        pegasos.train(samples[2],+1);
        pegasos.train(samples[3],-1);
        pegasos.train(samples[4],-1);
        pegasos.train(samples[5],-1);

        cout<< pegasos(samples[0]) <<endl;
        cout<< pegasos(samples[1]) <<endl;
        cout<< pegasos(samples[2]) <<endl;
        cout<< pegasos(samples[3]) <<endl;
        cout<< pegasos(samples[4]) <<endl;
        cout<< pegasos(samples[5]) <<endl;

        pegasos.clear();
    }
}
```

The output that I get:

```
0.0000000010
-3963387.1199921928
-3541750.1923335334
-4026632.6591409920
-3162276.9574407390
-3246604.3429724714
-2614148.9514844813
0.0000000100
-1253333.0548153266
-1119999.7511116527
-1273333.0503708781
-999999.7777783460
-1026666.4385190808
-826666.4829635697
0.0000001000
-396338.7119995961
-354175.0192337657
-402663.2659144707
-316227.6957445183
-324660.4342976844
-261414.8951489388
0.0000010000
-125333.3054819095
-111999.9751115777
-127333.3050374593
-99999.9777782790
-102666.6438523454
-82666.6482968476
0.0000100000
-39633.8712003365
-35417.5019237890
-40266.3265918186
-31622.7695748963
-32466.0434302058
-26141.4895153846
0.0001000000
-12533.3305485679
-11199.9975115703
-12733.3305041176
-9999.9977782724
-10266.6643856720
-8266.6648301755
0.0010000000
-3963.3871204108
-3541.7501927916
-4026.6326595536
-3162.2769579343
-3246.6043434582
-2614.1489520294
0.0100000000
-1253.3330552344
-1119.9997515702
-1273.3330507840
-999.9997782725
-1026.6664390053
-826.6664835091
0.1000000000
-396.3387124203
-354.1750196940
-402.6632663292
-316.2276962404
-324.6604347856
-261.4148956963
1.0000000000
-125.3333059077
-111.9999755772
-127.3333054573
-99.9999782797
-102.6666443458
-82.6666488500
10.0000000000
-39.6338716427
-35.4175024067
-40.2663270281
-31.6227700943
-32.4660439415
-26.1414900875
100.0000000000
-12.5333310483
-11.1999980544
-12.7333309973
-9.9999983600
-10.2666649587
-8.2666654680
1000.0000000000
-3.7091542406
-3.3145634810
-3.7683428546
-2.9594317974
-3.0383499493
-2.4464638100
10000.0000000000
-0.4292670207
-0.3836003494
-0.4361170215
-0.3425003451
-0.3516336794
-0.2831336723
100000.0000000000
0.0372866667
0.0333200000
0.0378816667
0.0297500000
0.0305433333
0.0245933333
1000000.0000000000
0.0037286667
0.0033320000
0.0037881667
0.0029750000
0.0030543333
0.0024593333
10000000.0000000000
0.0003728667
0.0003332000
0.0003788167
0.0002975000
0.0003054333
0.0002459333
100000000.0000000000
0.0000372867
0.0000333200
0.0000378817
0.0000297500
0.0000305433
0.0000245933
1000000000.0000000000
0.0000037287
0.0000033320
0.0000037882
0.0000029750
0.0000030543
0.0000024593
10000000000.0000000000
0.0000003729
0.0000003332
0.0000003788
0.0000002975
0.0000003054
0.0000002459
100000000000.0000000000
0.0000000373
0.0000000333
0.0000000379
0.0000000297
0.0000000305
0.0000000246
```

So the problem that I get all samples predicted as negative or positive.

**UPDATE:**

Problem solved:

https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/49

Answer (score 1):

This is an online learning algorithm based on stochastic gradient descent.  Each time you call train() it takes one gradient step, so you must call train() way more than 6 times.

You are also probably better of using a batch algorithm rather than an online algorithm.  Use this guide to pick one that is appropriate for your task: http://dlib.net/ml_guide.svg